# How to remove innerHTML value to be shown initially

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a multiplication table in JavaScript. The user is prompted to provide the Table number (1 to 10) after which all the question marks ('?') are replaced with that number. The user then needs to enter the answers in all the provided text fields. Finally, the user will have the option to check the answer (i.e. whether it is right or wrong).

When I run my code. After entering the user data to prompt it shows `Incorrect` infront of each `textfield` and the user entered value just before the `Check answers` button. How can I remove them to be shown initially.

Output:
My code:

```
function result() {
    var value = document.getElementById("a1").value;
    var checkMessageSpan1 = document.getElementById("checkMessage1");
    var checkMessageSpan2 = document.getElementById("checkMessage2");
    var r = x * 1;
    if (value == x) {
    checkMessageSpan1.innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:green\">"+"Correct!";
    }else{
    checkMessageSpan1.innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:red\">"+"Incorrect!";
    }



    var value = document.getElementById("a2").value;
    var r = x * 2;
    if (value == r) {
    checkMessageSpan2.innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:green\">"+"Correct!";
    }else{
    checkMessageSpan2.innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:red\">"+"Incorrect!";
    }


</script>
<button onClick="alert_field()"> Generate Question</button><br><br>

<p id="s1">
? x 1 = <input type="text"  id="a1"><span id="checkMessage1"></span><br>
? x 2 = <input type="text"  id="a2"><span id="checkMessage2"></span><br>

</p><br><br>
<p id="a"></p>
```

Check answers

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_. Either use a class or get the elements by their tag name. For both approaches have a look at: [javascript - What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code:

```
var value = document.getElementById("a1").value;
if (checkMessageSpan1.style.display === "none") {
    checkMessageSpan1.style.display = "inline-block";
} else {
    checkMessageSpan1.style.display = "none";
}

var value = document.getElementById("a2").value;
if (checkMessageSpan2.style.display === "none") {
    checkMessageSpan2.style.display = "inline-block";
} else {
    checkMessageSpan2.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For replacing all special characters, you may leverage regular expressions in js 
`var res=str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,x);` instead of 
`var res = str.replace("?",x);`

More on Regular expressions in JS `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions`

Comment: 'g' switch specified in regular expression above, does a global search for the contents of the variable x and to find all occurences of special characters.
Perhaps, if you could elaborate the actual use case, there could be other approach at this problem.